# Should I leave gap between my house's slab and a new one I'm laying outside in the garden?

Tags: concrete, outdoor, brick

I'm planning an outdoor kitchen.

This will be a simple brick sided bench about 3 metres long and maybe 800 mm deep.

I'm going to build it on a slab to support the weight and ensure a level surface.

As one end of the bench will butt onto the side of my house, I was wondering if there are reasons for or against leaving a gap between the new slab and the house's one.

I would like to not have a gap in the brickwork so as not to leave sanctuary for spiders and other creatures (I live in Australia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to leave an expansion gap. However,  you can fill the seam using a flexible material. Foam rod covered with a seam filler, is one common solution.  There are also products sold that can simply be pushed into the seam.

Check your local hardware/home improvement store, to see what's available in your area.

Comment: So - that gap is between both the slabs and the bricks?

Comment: Yes.  A gap between the two slabs, and a gap between the house and the bricks.  You want everything to be able to move, without pushing anything else out of whack.